# Should Android in-app billing work during debug?

Tags: android, android-studio, google-play, in-app-purchase

Will in-app purchases work if I run/debug app on my phone with Android Studio OR it should work only after publishing it on App Store as Alpha/Beta/Production, due to correct signature stuff or something else?

Comment: This is already documented in in app billing testing section . So instead of posting question here just Google it .

Comment: I did it, but didn't find direct answer

Comment: Possible duplicate of [Is it possible to debug locally Google Play's in-app billing in Android Studio?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/36113347/is-it-possible-to-debug-locally-google-plays-in-app-billing-in-android-studio)