# Error "Your transaction cannot be completed" when testing google play purchase

Tags: android, google-play, android-testing, android-inapp-purchase

I am trying to purchase using a beta tester but i am getting this error.
[image]

This is an error that shows in google play window, after passing initial validations and after the user press subscribe button, so i guess it is not an code or configuration error.

Anyway i checked this link https://stackoverflow.com/a/22469253/2700303 and also downloaded the app from the store.

I check the "Learn more" link that comes with the error but nothing on that troubleshooting page helped.
The account used as a valid and active pay method.
I am running on a simulator, but google play comes with it for a reason, so i discard that also.
The rest of the suggestions say to use other device. My simulator is running API 28 so should be good enough.

Comment: Purchase shall be tested on real device with production apk.
I think your issue is emulator with debug version.

Comment: If i remember correctly it worked in the past. I have many subscriptions canceled on google play console that i believe that all were made in the emulator

Comment: Please check my answer,

Answer (score 1):

- In-app purchase must be tested with production build on real device.

Steps

1. Generate release build from Android studio.
2. Uninstall debug app from your device, or use `adb uninstall`.

> adb uninstall {yourdomain}.{yourpackagename}

3. Install your release version to your device.

> adb install app-release.apk

**Update:**
Check this [answer](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/36113347/is-it-possible-to-debug-locally-google-plays-in-app-billing-in-android-studio) for more details.

**Update 2** :Please read more about [Test Google Play Billing](https://developer.android.com/google/play/billing/billing_testing)

Comment: "In-app purchase must be tested with production build on real device." is not accurate. I do purchases from a simulator device. Check  https://stackoverflow.com/a/41176362/2700303

Comment: @Check my update answer update you will that it reference to the same question that you mentioned.

Comment: You point to the question and the question have different answers. I pointed to a specific answer that shows how to test on a device simulator. And i confirm that can be done because i am testing purchases on the simulator successfully now.

Comment: @ByteArtisan According to Google Doc, **You can test on any Android-powered hardware device running Android 1.6 or higher.**, Please read [Test Google Play Billing](https://developer.android.com/google/play/billing/billing_testing)