# skuDetailsList is empty when using different build variant

Tags: android, in-app-purchase

Well, when I try to test in-app purchases and use production build, then `skuDetailsList` is not empty and works great, but when I try to test in development build, then the `skuDetailsList` is empty. Why is that? How can I manage changes in Google Console to avoid list being empty on development build?

Additional info: For instance, I've an application MyApp1.apk published on GooglePlayStore. This .apk is build using "ProductionFlavor" (buildVariant). Then, I create the MyApp1.apk version, but change buildVaraint to "TestFlavor". For in-app billing tests to work, I have to upload which version to alpha channel? The Production one or Test one (I'm gonna be testing "test" version) or it does not matter as the signing is same?

Comment: Possible duplicate of [Is it possible to debug locally Google Play's in-app billing in Android Studio?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/36113347/is-it-possible-to-debug-locally-google-plays-in-app-billing-in-android-studio)

Comment: @greeble31 Updated question.