# Does anyone have any suggestions on how to debug in app purchases on Android on react native?

Tags: android, react-native

I am looking for a way to debug in app purchases on Android in react native. I would like to be able to step through code using the react native debugger but my research indicates that you can only test in app purchases on android on a release build. What have you guys done to be able to debug in app purchases on Android?

Comment: Have you already checked out this https://stackoverflow.com/questions/36113347/is-it-possible-to-debug-locally-google-plays-in-app-billing-in-android-studio

Comment: thanks for your response. checked it out but am looking for a react native specific solution whereby I can step through the react native code while debugging